# Text-Transform Style Not Working

Tags: html, button, text, css

I'm trying to make the text inside my buttons all caps, but for some reason, it's not picking up my CSS changes. It's still normal caps in both Firefox and Chrome.

[Here is the page.](http://ytbpulse.com/event/east-elmhurst-ny-nyc-presentation-and-boot-camp/)

This is the HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.eventbrite.com/e/ytb-boot-camp-weekend-tickets-11133581843?aff=es2&rank=0"><button>Click Here to Register</button></a>
```

This is the CSS:

```
button, .button {
    background-color: #f22f04;
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
}

p a button {
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Seems like it should be a simple fix, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What do you mean it's still "normal caps"? Seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mMu4R/

Comment: It works fine on its own (http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/qDbhw), but I'm not seeing any such CSS rules (overridden or otherwise) applied to those elements in your page. In which of the many linked stylesheets on that page would this rule be found?

Comment: i tried your code and everything looks ok, the button seems to be transformed

Comment: Yeah, nothing is showing up for me either when I inspect element. Check your selectors (make sure they're not hidden in a different media query). I always find myself forgetting the commas when selecting 2 elements or forgetting to close brackets, so that could be your issue (unless you copy-pasted here).

Comment: what's the order of loading of the stylesheets? (one may be overriding your code - which looks good to me)

Comment: Are you sure you updated the site with the `text-transform`? When I inspect the button, there isn't any `text-transform` style on it at all. The CSS you provided is not on your page. Perhaps forgot to compile or something

Comment: Yes, I am sure that I uploaded the stylesheet. The styles are located in style.css. I don't know why they aren't appearing...

Comment: Looking in http://ytbpulse.com/wp-content/themes/reverie-ytb/css/style.css, I am not seeing any instances of `text-transform`.

Comment: the style.css file does not contain any text-transform style for button element at all.  Look at the css source file on the server, it's not there.

Comment: @mcography figure that out and your problem is solved. Is it just a plain css file or does your server use a css preprocessor?

Comment: @Huangism I'm not sure. My hosting service is GoDaddy. Sometimes when I refresh the page, I see the change but then it disappears. Like every 4th or 5th refresh, it will appear. But then I'll refresh again and it will disappear again. I think this must be a GoDaddy issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

this is the code from your style.css:

```
/* BUTTON STYLES */

button, .button {
    background-color: #f22f04;
}
```

found here: http://ytbpulse.com/wp-content/themes/reverie-ytb/css/style.css

Maybe your stylesheet hasn't been properly updated on the server?

Comment: Do you know why my stylesheet wouldn't be updated? I'm using GoDaddy. I thought that maybe if I left it for a day, the stylesheet would be updated, but it's still not working properly. I see the change sometimes (like on every 4th or 5th refresh), but then it disappears again.

Comment: It could be due to browser caching, but that would not explain why I can't see your changes on multiple refreshes. It looks like you're using Wordpress as your CMS, and GoDaddy for hosting. Wordpress may be caching something, and not "publishing" to the server, but without looking at your Wordpress / FTP configuration, it would be hard to diagnose.